# create tls secret from environment variables in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

Is there a way to create a tls secret in Kubernetes from environment variables instead of files?

For example

```
kubectl create secret tls secret-tls --cert $ENV1 --key $ENV2
```

Comment: Yes the command you wrote will work in bash if environment variables are properly set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Run the help cmd.

```sh
$ kubectl create secret tls --help
Create a TLS secret from the given public/private key pair.

 The public/private key pair must exist before hand. The public key certificate must be .PEM encoded and match the given
private key.

Examples:
  # Create a new TLS secret named tls-secret with the given key pair:
  kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --cert=path/to/tls.cert --key=path/to/tls.key

Options:
      --allow-missing-template-keys=true: If true, ignore any errors in templates when a field or map key is missing in
the template. Only applies to golang and jsonpath output formats.
      --append-hash=false: Append a hash of the secret to its name.
      --cert='': Path to PEM encoded public key certificate.
      --dry-run=false: If true, only print the object that would be sent, without sending it.
      --generator='secret-for-tls/v1': The name of the API generator to use.
      --key='': Path to private key associated with given certificate.
  -o, --output='': Output format. One of:
json|yaml|name|go-template|go-template-file|template|templatefile|jsonpath|jsonpath-file.
      --save-config=false: If true, the configuration of current object will be saved in its annotation. Otherwise, the
annotation will be unchanged. This flag is useful when you want to perform kubectl apply on this object in the future.
      --template='': Template string or path to template file to use when -o=go-template, -o=go-template-file. The
template format is golang templates [http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview].
      --validate=true: If true, use a schema to validate the input before sending it

Usage:
  kubectl create secret tls NAME --cert=path/to/cert/file --key=path/to/key/file [--dry-run] [options]

Use "kubectl options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).
```

> If you want to use data from your environment, then set the cert and
> key files path to env variables. Not the data themselves.